# A CMS has been renamed - should I create a new tag, or alias the old tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

A CMS - Composite C1, has been renamed to Orckestra CMS after a buyout.

Should I create a new tag, or alias the old tag?

If so how do I create an alias? (I have found the official repository but not a way to create an alias).

Comment: An alias should be created. You can suggest alias from `https://stackoverflow.com/tags/TAGNAME/synonyms`. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-c1/synonyms). You can also edit the tag info to inform others, something like "THIS CMS IS RENAMED TO .... USE ... TAG FROM NOW TO REFER TO ..."

Comment: If the old versions still use the old name, it is relevant to keep the tag for those purposes. If it has been completely renamed and is in all other instances referred to by the new name, then a synonym would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I need 2500 rep and have 2200 so I can't add this alias.